# sqlite expensive_function query optimizer

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table schema is:

```
create table test_table (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, feature blob)
```

eg data:

```
id      feature
1       blob=bytes[512]=float[128] eg[0.01,111,232....]
2       blob=bytes[512]=float[128] eg[0.02,113,-22....]
3       blob=bytes[512]=float[128] eg[2222,113,-22....]
```

UDF cosine_distance is custom function with two blob args.
The column feature is a blob for an float array (float[128])，Then I want to calculate the cosine distance.
I have a sql with an expensive_function cosine_distance (udf) with sqlite.

```
select cosine_distance(a,?) as distance 
from test_table 
where distance >=? 
order by distance desc limit ?
```

In this sql cosine_distance function will call twice in sqlite.
How to let the cosine_distance (a expensive_function) only execute once?

When i use a subselect such as:

```
select * from (select cosine_distance(feature,?) d from test_table) nt 
where nt.d>? 
order by nt.d desc limit ?
```

UDF cosine_distance will execute twice every record.

When table test_table have **5** records.cosine_distance will be invoked **10** times.But the cosine_distance is very expensive.

Comment: Did you flag the function as deterministic when you created it?

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Comment: @Shawn  not mark as deterministic. but I just mark it as deterministic.the function will be still called twice

Comment: why are you using an underline on "expensive function"?

Comment: you can also create a column to store the calculated value and even index this column. each time you insert or update values on a row, update the new column. this update could also be implemented with a trigger

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a LIMIT on the subquery, like this:

```
select * from (select cosine_distance(feature,?) as d from test_table limit -1) nt 
where nt.d>? 
order by nt.d desc limit ?
```

This may disable the [subquery flatenning](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening) according to rule 13.

Option 2: using an OFFSET on the subquery:

```
select * from (select cosine_distance(feature,?) as d from test_table offset 0) nt 
where nt.d>? 
order by nt.d desc limit ?
```

Option 3: using ORDER BY on both queries:

```
select * from (select cosine_distance(feature,?) as d from test_table order by d) nt 
where nt.d>? 
order by nt.d desc limit ?
```